# Difference between array types - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a difference between this syntax of array?

coming from a `dd()`

```
$array:3 = [
  0 => "email"
  1 => " email"
  2 => " email"
]
```

vs

`$array = ['email', 'email', 'email']`

I am doing this:

`$email->bcc($bccEmailsArray);` which is the 1st code snippet, and it doesn't work. If I put in the 2nd code snippet, it works.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: The only practical difference I see is that the first array has values with spaces while the second does not.

Comment: Oh, and the `array:3` part is not valid syntax.

Comment: The first one doesn't really look like PHP code. It looks like a `print_r` output. Can you show how you're using those in your code?

Comment: The first doesn't have comma delimiters... white space isn't interpreted in PHP like it is in languages such as Python

Comment: As we don't know which library you use for sending the mails we can't give an answer to this.

Comment: I should have put in the post that the first example is coming from a dd();

Answer (score 1):

Like what others are saying your problem is **just syntax**. because of dd() it appears? dd() var_dump() etc are for debugging.

```
$array:3 = [     // :3 is not valid
  0 => "email"   //no commas
  1 => " email"  //no commas + extra spaces in emails
  2 => " email"  //no commas + extra spaces in emails
]
```

Correct it to :

```
$array = [
  0 => "email",
  1 => "email",
  2 => "email",
]
```

or to either of these :

```
$array = [0=>"email",1 => "email",2 => "email"];
$array = array(0=>"email", 1=>"email", 2=>"email");
```

or just to:

```
$array = array("email","email","email");
```

as this will just produce default keys:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "email"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "email"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "email"
}
```

Hence there is no difference between the two if the syntax is correct.

More information:

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp
  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp
  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm
- https://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/

Comment: Thanks I'm brain dead today fixing it now ... it's supposed to be array()

Comment: I should have put in the post that the first example is coming from a dd()

Comment: @AustinHunter ok then you just need to remove the dd() from your code,??

Answer (score 0):

The main difference if fact that first sample is not valid PHP code.

Part `array:3` makes it invalid.

Valid examples would be

```
$array = [
  0 => "email",
  1 => "email",
  2 => "email"
];
```

and

```
$array = ['email', 'email', 'email'];
```

Beside the fact that in first example some "emails" start with space both arrays are equals. If you don't provide keys explicitly, elements will be numbered starting from 0.

For more info you can refer to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: you should use comma

Comment: I should have put in the post that the first example is coming from a dd()

Comment: @AustinHunter can you explain then what do you mean by `it doesn't work`? There is error, something is happening, something is not happening?